# Should Artifacts be improved if Epic Level Handbook is introduced to the campaign?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, epic-tier, artifacts

As a recent research, I found that it seems artifacts were designed in the pre-epic era, so their CLs are 20th at most and (if it is a weapon or an armour) can have at most +5 enhancement bonus, which would give them a hard time on things like DR x/Epic (it's kinda weird since I thought Solar Angel is designed in the pre-epic era as well, yet artifacts cannot penetrate its defence).

Perhaps it would be more reasonable to boost their enhancement bonus at least (if any) to +6 or more and increase their CL accordingly? Or is there any revision on them after ELH comes out (it would be better if there's an official fix for this)?

(e.g. As a major artifact, *The Saint's Mace* is a +5 heavy mace and it cannot get through DR x/Epic.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You could pay to upgrade the weapon.

This actually came up in a D&D 3.5 campaign I played in, which reached epic levels. The party's fighter wielded a +5 artifact greatsword, but soon started facing creatures with epic damage reduction. The solution was to simply pay an epic mage to upgrade the weapon to +6.

Upgrading a weapon's enhancement by paying the difference is a standard rule. From the SRD, Creating Magic Items, "Adding New Abilities":

> A creator can add new magical abilities to a magic item with no restrictions. The cost to do this is the same as if the item was not magical. Thus, a +1 longsword can be made into a +2 vorpal longsword, with the cost to create it being equal to that of a +2 vorpal sword minus the cost of a +1 sword.

Artifacts cannot be created, but there's no rule which says they can't be upgraded.

#### What does it cost?

Artifacts technically have no price. To calculate the value of the base weapon, you'd usually do the following:

- Properties priced in plusses add up. Since the Flaming property costs equivalent to a +1, upgrading a *+2 flaming sword* to a *+3 flaming sword* costs as much as upgrading a +3 sword to a +4.

  - Further, according to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195925/40971), you start paying the epic price as soon as the plus exceeds +5. A +6 sword upgraded to add the Flaming property is paying the epic price of 260,000 gp for it, the same as if they upgraded a +6 to a +7 sword.
- Secondary properties on specific weapons usually have a fixed price, and don't increase the cost of upgrading plusses. Upgrading a *+2 luck blade* to a *+3 luck blade* costs the same as upgrading a +2 weapon to a +3 weapon. They can be ignored when calculating upgrade prices.

Therefore, for example:

- A +5 weapon is 50,000 gp, while a +6 weapon is 720,000 gp, for a difference in cost of 670,000 gp.
- The Saint's Mace, in particular, is a +5 holy lawful disruption weapon, so its base price is as a +11 weapon, already epic. Upgrading it to +6 would cost the difference between +11 and +12, which is actually less: 460,000 gp.

This is all very expensive, when you consider that starting gold for a 21st level character is still less than a million gold pieces.

#### There was originally a feat for this situation.

The original 3.0 Epic Level Handbook had a feat called Penetrate Damage Reduction, which caused your weapons to count as +2 higher than normal for the purposes of damage reduction. A +4 or weapon would therefore count as +6 for the purposes of overcoming damage reduction. This feat easily handled the specific case of the 20th level fighter with a +5 sword.

The D&D 3.5 errata document for the book changed the feat, so it only allows you to overcome damage reduction to specific materials. D&D 3.5 also changed existing creatures to have epic damage reduction (solar, tarrasque). I don't think it would be unreasonable to allow an epic feat which allows all of a character's attacks to overcome epic damage reduction (it may even be weak when they acquire a +6 weapon which supercedes the feat's benefit).

#### You could also just ad-hoc it.

As a DM, you can always just give the artifact the unique ability to overcome epic damage reduction. Adding secret additional powers to artifacts is a tradition that goes back to their earliest appearance in *Eldritch Wizardry*.

Answer (score 1):

For now, for those +5 Artifacts, I would just give them an additional +1 to make them epic weapons (like the weapon those deities are wielding). That seems to make more sense to me.

Theoretically, artifacts (since all of them are +5 weapons/armors if they are not wonderous items) are meant to be the top tier items in the game. So it only make senses to make them Epic if the Epic rule has been applied.

As an alternative solution (if I don't want to change their in-game stats), I may claim that those artifacts can overcome Epic damage reductions or the like since "they are artifacts". Usually they would have some special powers to make them being special despite of having a lower enhancement bonus. Letting them overcome the Epic DRs should be sufficient in most cases. (And adding that +1 won't do much if the Epic DRs has been overcome already.)

Comment: Self-answered questions are subject to the same (or higher) standards as other questions. You're answer still needs to be supported not just *"I would do this"*. See [this self-answering meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/what-should-i-consider-before-posting-a-question-and-answer-it-myself) for more information.